# libgdx viewport fit different screens

Tags: libgdx, viewport

I'm having a problem with fitting my game on different screens.
I declared a viewport width and height in my stage class.

```
public static final int VIEWPORT_WIDTH = 20;
public static final int VIEWPORT_HEIGHT = 30;
```

And i set up the camera

```
camera = new OrthographicCamera(VIEWPORT_WIDTH, VIEWPORT_HEIGHT);
camera.position.set(camera.viewportWidth/2, camera.viewportHeight/2, 0f);
```

And i set the screen width and height in desktop app to this

```
public static final int APP_WIDTH = 800;
public static final int APP_HEIGHT = 900;
```

On desktop everything looks fine but on my android device it looks stretched upwards. I read the documentation about viewports but how can I implement it here using these variables? I know similar questions have been asked but I would like to know viewports can be implemented using these specific variables, that way I might understand it better.

Comment: Did you update the viewport with screen sizes when the screen is resized?

Comment: No I didn't even know I had to do that, but it works now. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably want to use an `ExtendViewport`. This extends the world 1 way to fill the entire screen.

your code would look something like this:

```
private Viewport viewport;
private Camera camera;

public void create() {
    camera = new OrthographicCamera();
    viewport = new ExtendViewport(VIEWPORT_WIDTH , VIEWPORT_HEIGHT, camera);
}


public void resize(int width, int height) {
    viewport.update(width, height);
}
```

Read more here: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Viewports#extendviewport

Comment: Yes thank you! I understand viewports better now and it works!

Comment: One more question: In my game I put the ground at y=0, but on my phone the ground is moved a bit upwards, around y = 2 I think. How do I solve this? Do I need to update all constants?

Comment: This is what extendviewport does. Your world still has the same aspect ratio, meaning that if the screen is higher, it will have unused space at the top and bottom. If you do not want this, you should calculate the difference (using aspect ratios and world size) and offset your camera accordingly